# Latency between thread test: Linux bare metal machine vs QNX on a VM

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, qnx

I recently did a latency comparison on these two setups:
a) Ubuntu 16.04 running on a 12 core host;
b) A guest QNX running a VMware on a laptop host (4 cores assigned to the QNX VM) - I do not have a better setup currently for QNX.

The test scenario:
10 threads running, each thread sends out a message to a randomly chosen receiving thread every 30ms-ish - very low message rate indeed; the message mechanism is implemented using conditional variables and each thread has its own dedicated rx prod-consumer queue and its own conditional variable and mutex - so no interference between queues. I measure the time between the message got constructed/sent and the receiving thread gets the message. The mean and std_dev min max are all captured for each thread.

The result is surprisingly favoring QNX (although it is running on a VM). 10us vs 40us.

for a thread on Linux (seconds): mean=0.000038076 std_dev=2.7523e-05 min=0.000000254 max=0.000177410 sampleSize=1023
for a thread QNX (seconds): mean=0.000011351 std_dev=0.000105937 min=0.000000000 max=0.000999987 sampleSize=969

I noticed that the QNX side the clock is not as precise (resolution wise) as the Linux side since I do see the min latency measurable is 0.

I just wonder if it conforms with other people's experiences - does Linux thread conditional wake-up take 40us in average?
Btw, if the QNX time precision is in 100us and Linux is in nanosec, does this diff impact stat? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're also measuring time taken to pass between threads, not just to wake up. Also, if the thread is actually asleep, it being told to wake up isn't a guaranty it will even happen this century. That's OS thread management. Also, if QNX's time take is less than its precision, then the value is probably meaningless.

Comment: What flavour of QNX?

Comment: You're testing on two very different hardware platforms. I don't think you can draw much in the way of meaningful conclusions from comparing the statistics you've collected.

Comment: Chris, thx for the comment. The test scenario is, each thread would be blocked by its prod-consume conditional var until a message got entered into it, then it wakes up (unblocked) and read the message. I measure what could be measured here and this is a realistic scenario for many applications. So I am not sure what u meant.

Comment: @user4581301, this is QNX VM for x86 (VMWARE) with a name QNX-SDP-x86_64 ver is 7.0.0

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes they r different, not by chioce - but the diff is supposed to favor Linux instead of QNX - the same program runs on a Linux VM (on same laptop) performs way worse than bare metal case.

Comment: @Sclaker, I understand that in a general sense, the Linux machine is better provisioned than the QNX VM.  But inasmuch as you don't know what specific factors may contribute to the phenomena you are measuring, it is not safe to assume that the provisioning difference gives any advantage to the Linux machine for the purposes of your experiment.  It may do, or maybe not. There's even a chance that it hinders the Linux machine rather than helping.  For your results to be in any way generalizable beyond your specific setup, you need better to control the variables.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sure - point taken. I am more curious about the Linux latency number I got - does it conform to how people feel? -  in a low message rate situation, it takes 40us for a Linux thread to wake up to a (conditional variable) message. This is a light load Linux host - pretty much nothing else was running on it other than the OS tasks and this test program.

Comment: I'm not prepared to comment on your specific latency number without reviewing the code for the test.  But I do now realize that there is a particular issue that may be affecting you: if your "12-core" test host in fact has a 6-core Intel CPU with hyperthreading enabled, then your 12 cores are not all fully independent of each other.  Your test uses enough threads that they could not each be assigned to a separate physical core on such a machine, and that could certainly have negative effects on timing via various mechanisms.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  very good point - see my posted answer - looks like my laptop does have a better performing CPU latency-wise than the monster Linux host's - both are pretty new machines though.

Answer (score 0):

The latency test turns out to be more sensitive (in a different way) to the HW than what I previous thought. The newer 12 core CPU host has hyper thread enabled and it produces 40us latency numbers. I moved to a older 4 CPU with hyper thread disabled machine, the latency number drops to 15-16us. That is in the same ball park range as the QNX VM number. I wish  I could make the platform more aligned in the tests to get a more conclusive answer in the future.

new Linux result: mean=0.000015819 std_dev=1.39205e-05 min=0.000000503 max=0.000117652 sampleSize=1528

Comment: VMware plays with the various system time sources to amortize the hypervisor overhead back into the virtual machines, and align the clock sources between cpus.   As a sort of gross test, try and jig your micro-benchmark to run continuously for 10 or 20 seconds, and use something external to cross validate the timing.   You may only be able to get 1/10s resolution, but it should show if there is a substantial deviation.  If I recall correctly, there is an "advanced" toggle in the menu / .vmx to adjust or disable this amortization.